# Audio input doesn't work, internal or external

Tags: debian, drivers, audio

I can't figure out why I can't make the audio input work on my HP Omen 15 ek0006nl.
In **settings/sound/input** I only find *Rear Microphone - Built-in Audio* with the volume bar stuck at a fixed level, and if I try to record something or make a call I receive a white noise.

A similar thing happens if I use my Bluetooth headset (Sony WH-1000XM3): the related audio input device is recognized but the volume bar in the settings is stuck at zero and I get no feedback. The very same happens if I use an external USB sound card (UGREEN FBA_30143).

In all the previous cases, *the output audio works perfectly*, with speakers, Bluetooth, 3.5mm jack and external USB sound card.

Here's something that may be useful.

Output of `aplay --list devices`

```
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC245 Analog [ALC245 Analog]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 9: HDMI 3 [HDMI 3]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 10: HDMI 4 [HDMI 4]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 11: HDMI 5 [HDMI 5]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

Output of `lspci | grep Audio`

```
00:1f.3 Multimedia audio controller: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH cAVS
```

Output of `cat /proc/asound/cards`

```
 0 [PCH            ]: HDA-Intel - HDA Intel PCH
                      HDA Intel PCH at 0x4042210000 irq 179
 1 [NVidia         ]: HDA-Intel - HDA NVidia
                      HDA NVidia at 0x78080000 irq 17
```

Output of `alsamixer`

[image]

I run Debian 10 bullseye 5.10.0-7-amd64 in dual boot with Windows 10, where the audio input works perfectly.

**EDIT**

`pactl info`

```
Server String: /run/user/1000/pulse/native
Library Protocol Version: 34
Server Protocol Version: 34
Is Local: yes
Client Index: 15
Tile Size: 65472
User Name: giorgio
Host Name: giorgio
Server Name: pulseaudio
Server Version: 14.2
Default Sample Specification: s16le 2ch 44100Hz
Default Channel Map: front-left,front-right
Default Sink: alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3.analog-surround-40
Default Source: alsa_input.pci-0000_00_1f.3.analog-stereo
Cookie: e45b:11eb
```

`pactl list sinks |grep -i -e description -e volume`

```
    Description: Built-in Audio Analog Surround 4.0
    Volume: front-left: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB,   front-right: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB,   rear-left: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB,   rear-right: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
    Base Volume: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
    Flags: HARDWARE HW_MUTE_CTRL HW_VOLUME_CTRL DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY 
        device.profile.description = "Analog Surround 4.0"
        device.description = "Built-in Audio Analog Surround 4.0"
```

Comment: Several volumes are at 0 in alsamixer. Have you tried raising them all? Is pulseaudio running? What does `pactl info` say? And `pactl list sinks |grep -i -e description -e volume`?

Comment: Please use [edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/654543/edit) and add information to question instead of posting as comments.

Comment: Also note that the `alsamixer` controls extend to the right (use arrows). Your `Capture` is in red, I've never seen this in `alsamixer`, but it looks suspicious. Also try `amixer` to see if there are any controls that need unmuting/volume setting. Pulseaudio may not be able to use the ALSA controls correctly, so for debugging, I'd disable pulseaudio (e.g. `pasuspend`, or `pulseaudio --kill` if your distro allows this) and try directly with alsa (`arecord -D ...`).

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' Since the question is about audio input (microphone), shouldn't the command be `pactl list sources |grep -i -e description -e volume` instead of sinks?